# Problem in understanding Blaschke product.

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, blaschke-products

Blaschke product is defined in the following way $:$

$$B(z) = \prod\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {|z_n|} {z_n} \frac {z_n - z} {1 - \overline z_n z},\ z_n \in \mathbb D \setminus \{\textbf 0\}\ \forall n$$

It can be shown that if $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1 - |z_n|) \lt \infty$ then the sequence of partial products of $B(z)$ converges uniformly for any $z \in \mathbb C$ with $|z| \leq r \lt 1.$ Hence by Morera's theorem $B(z)$ gives rise to a holomorphic function on the open unit disk $\mathbb D.$ Now since $z_n$'s are confined in a bounded set $\mathbb D$ and  are zeros of a holomorphic function given by the Blaschke product $B(z)$ it turns out that each $z_n$ has finite multiplicity and  hence the range of the sequence $\{z_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is a bounded infinite subset of $\mathbb C$ and hence by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem it has an accumulation point. But then the identity theorem asserts that $B(z)$ is identically zero on $\mathbb D.$ Where did I make mistake?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for investing your valuable time on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $z_n$ accumulate at a point on the boundary of the open set $\mathbb D$, not within $\mathbb D$, so the identity theorem does not apply. That theorem requires your function to be analytic in an open neighborhood around your accumulation point.

Comment: Ah! I just saw that. Blaschke condition indicates that $|z_n| \to 1.$ So the zeros are approaching to the boundary. I am sorry that I couldn't see that at my first glance.

Comment: No worries, mate.

Comment: Is there any book which deals with non-tangential limits of the Blaschke product? I am having hard time showing that the non-tangential limits of the Blaschke product exist. For the simplified case we could have started to turn our attention to finding the radial limits. If $z$ is lying on the unit circle what can we say about $B(z)\ $? Is it convergent?

Comment: look up any Hardy space book or book about bounded analytic function, inner functions etc - would recommend Mashreghi Derivatives of Inner Functions for a more in-depth take with interesting examples of infinite Blaschke products; the product for $B$ converges normally to an analytic function on the closure of the complement of the poles so on the closure of $\mathbb C -\cup_{z_n \ne 0}\frac{1}{\bar z_n}$

Comment: @Conrad$:$ When we are talking about the existence of radial limits of the Blaschke product is it meant that the limit $$\lim\limits_{r \to 1^-} \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} B_N (re^{i \theta}) = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} B_N (e^{i \theta}).$$

Comment: In general the limits might not commute. For instance one could have taken $z_n = 1 - \frac {1} {2^n}$ and $\theta = 0.$

Comment: As long as zeroes do not accumulate at a boundary point, the Blaschke product is analytic there so all good; when the points accumulate like in your example, it depends on the case - the radial limit may or may not exist, it may or may not be of modulus $1$ etc; note that on the boundary the Blaschke finite subproducts are always of modulus $1$ so if $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} B_N (e^{i \theta})$ exist it must have modulus $1$, but said limit may or may not exist either; pretty much everything can happen I think, the only thing one can say is that the radial limit exists ae

Comment: for example look at the Blaschke product (first, of course, prove that is a Blaschke product and find its zeroes!) $\frac{2e^{-\frac{1+z}{1-z}}-1}{e^{-\frac{1+z}{1-z}}-2}$ and see what happens at $1$ eg radially (and nonntagentially) it goes to $1/2$ despite that the zeroes accumulate at $1$ so there is a sequence converging to $1$ on which $B \to 0$ there, while of course on the unit circle the partial product have absolute value $1$ near $1$ and $B$ is analytic at every point on the circle different from $1$

Comment: @Conrad: Another question which arises in my mind is : What is the reason of multiplying unimodular constants with the terms of the infinite Blaschke product? There should be some reason behind that.

Comment: for the convergence of the infinite Blaschke product - note that the zero condition is just a condition on the modulus and magically one doesn't need any condition on the arguments of $z_n$ at the price of that term depending on their arguments (remembering that in an infinite product $\Pi a_n$ what counts is the behaviour of $|1-a_n|$ and here this depends on the arguments of $z_n$ and not only on their modulus

Comment: with that extra unimodular term, one takes $1-|z_n|$ factor when doing $1-\frac {|z_n|} {z_n} \frac {z_n - z} {1 - \overline z_n z}$ and the other factor term is easily seen to be uniformly bounded for $|z| \le r<1 , |z_n| > \frac{r+1}{2}$ say so the normal convergence (absolute and uniform on compact) follows when $\sum (1-|z_n|) < \infty$